# How to import a .txt format file into Python, with a regular column structure (but not reliable separators such as tab, comma, etc.)

Tags: python, dataframe, import

I am working with Center for Disease Control (CDC) raw text file (.txt) - which has no header - and want to import the data for use in Python. The CDC provides a codebook for fields by column:

```
 - Columns 1-6       - FILLER space (blank space, unused)
 - Column 7          - version field (A or S)
 - Columns 8-9       - FILLER space (blank space, unused)
 - Column 10         - numeric flag    (1 or 2)
 - Columns 11-14     - numeric field for year
 - Columns 15-16     - numeric field for month
 - Columns 17-20     - FILLER space (blank, unused)
 - Columns 21-24     - numeric field for time
 - Columns 25     - numeric field for day of the week
 - ...
 - Column 439 - text field
 - Column 440 - numeric field
 - Columns 441-3050 - FILLER space
```

Here is a first-line sample of the raw data (minus the first six blank columns):

```
     A  2201701    10462        11                1                                 36116      1                                 1  3033    0833                               99110300  3         05206021                        N00000000N    6034.84   178 NNNNNNXXY03 2222124N4222NN1                 1              M 07  2016     2504325  25043    1130051 NYYY           P038                                    058     1
```

Here is an early attempt:

```
    CHS2 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\CDC\FetalDeaths\2017_FET_Analysis_Public_US_20190219.txt', header=None)
    CHS2.info()
```

which leads to the following:

```
>    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
>    RangeIndex: 49170 entries, 0 to 49169
>    Data columns (total 1 columns):
>    0    49170 non-null object
>    dtypes: object(1)
>    memory usage: 384.2+ KB
```

As someone still learning Python, I am trying to discover how to import such data. A standard delimiter (e.g. comma) doesn't seem appropriate here. I haven't come across a similar question on Stack Overflow yet. What might someone suggest? Also, how to import only specific columns and format them? It will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can convert the file's lines to have consistent delimiters:

```
with open(r'C:\Users\jfrya\OneDrive\Desktop\COVID19\US_counties\CDC\FetalDeaths\2017_FET_Analysis_Public_US_20190219.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    
data = '\n'.join([','.join([s for s in line.split() if s]) for line in lines])
```

Comment: Thank you, although when I tried this it gave me the following:File "<ipython-input-5-ed6c0aab15c9>", line 1
    with open('C:\Users\jfrya\OneDrive\Desktop\COVID19\US_counties\CDC\FetalDeaths\2017_FET_Analysis_Public_US_20190219.txt', 'r') as f:
             ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: change `open('C:\Users\jfrya\OneDrive\Desktop\COVID19\US_counties\CDC\FetalDeaths\2017_FET_Analysis_Public_US_20190219.txt', 'r')` to `open(r'C:\Users\jfrya\OneDrive\Desktop\COVID19\US_counties\CDC\FetalDeaths\2017_FET_Analysis_Public_US_20190219.txt', 'r')`.

Comment: Thanks for the emendation!

Comment: @JohnFrancis My pleasure. Please consider [upvoting answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) that solved your problem. Thank you!